# Python: How to Produce a File of the "Missing Elements"

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a set of data in xml, which goes something like:

```
<widgets>
<widget number = 'a1'>
...
info regarding widget a1
...
</widget>
<widget number = 'a2'>
...
info regarding widget a2
...
</widget>
...
...
...
<widget number = 'a10000000000000000'>
...
info regarding widget a10000000000000000
...
</widget>
</widgets>
```

I've am parsing the file, looking for information on each widget, which is going fine.

I am looking for a way to produce a csv of the "missing" widgets. They are in numeric order (ie., a2 should follow a1, a3 follows a2, etc), but there could be some missing ones.

I have gotten as far as needing to strip the 'a' off of the front, but I am not sure how to set something up where if there is a "skip", everything gets added to the "skipped" file.

Perhaps, this would be more easily illustrated by an example. If I have:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    ...
    info regarding widget a10
    ...
    
    
    ...
    info regarding widget a12
    ...
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
I'd want a list with 'a11', since that is the missing one.

If I had: 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    
    ...
    info regarding widget a17
    ...
    
    
    ...
    info regarding widget a20
    ...
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
I'd want a list with 
a18
a19

and so on. I know how to get the list into a csv, so all I am really looking for is how to generate that first list by figuring out that there is a skip, evaluating the size of the skip and then adding entries to the list using a for loop.

Comment: Did my answer do what you needed?

Comment: Hi Bill, yes thanks, I was able to modify it to fit the rest of the code, appreciate it!

Comment: On SO you should, please, mark an answer 'accepted' when it meets your requirements. In any case, you're most welcome!

Comment: @BillBell I think I just did :)

Comment: And thank you! Others will appreciate it when you do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I create an xml file of widgets with some gaps. Then I parse it using the lxml library and find the collect of `widget` elements using an xpath expression. I pick out the `number` attribute from each of these elements and then the slice containing the number in a list comprehension to have the numbers of all `available_widgets`.

At this point I take the coward's way out: I assume that the range of possible widget numbers is small. I spin through the range represented by `available_widgets` to see which are missing.

If, in fact, you need to look through a large range of possibilities then you can likely find a recipe for finding gaps in lists or sequences somewhere here on SO.

```
>>> nums = [1,2,3,5,6,8,11,14,17,20]
>>> with open('temp.xml', 'w') as temp:
...     r = temp.write('<widgets>')
...     for num in nums:
...         r = temp.write('<widget number="a%s">'%num)
...         r = temp.write('info regarding widget a%s'%num)
...         r =temp.write('</widget>')
...     r = temp.write('</widgets>')
... 
>>> 
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.parse('temp.xml')
>>> widgets = tree.xpath('.//widget')
>>> available_widgets = [int(widget.attrib['number'][1:]) for widget in widgets]
>>> available_widgets 
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]
>>> missing_widgets = []
>>> for num in range(min(available_widgets), max(available_widgets)+1):
...     if not num in available_widgets:
...         missing_widgets.append(num)
...         
>>> missing_widgets 
[4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19]
```